# Restricted phpmyadmin to locahost doesn't work

Tags: windows, xampp, phpmyadmin

This is my httpd-xampp.conf snippet for phpMyAdmin

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    #Require all granted
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    #ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

I've used http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ and http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/
both doesn't work. I'll get an error 403.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that this is Apache 2.4 and you are using configuration for 2.2?

> In 2.2, access control based on client hostname, IP address, and other
>   characteristics of client requests was done using the directives
>   `Order`, `Allow`, `Deny`, and `Satisfy`.
>
> In 2.4, such access control is done
>   in the same way as other authorization checks, using the new module
>   [mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_host.html). The old access control idioms should be replaced by
>   the new authentication mechanisms, although for compatibility with old
>   configurations, the new module [mod_access_compat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html) is provided.

Easiest way to achieve this on 2.4 would be replacing all `Allow`/`Deny` with

```
Require local
```

> The `local` provider allows access to the server if any of the following
>   conditions is true:
>
> - the client address matches `127.0.0.0/8`
> - the client address is `::1`
> - both the client and the server address of the connection are the same